# java script календарь. не могу не могу убрать даты в конце

Tags: javascript

Есть функция добавления календаря, я в js не очень еще разбираюсь и есть два вопроса.

1) Функция  добавляет в конце месяца ячейки с числами следующего месяца, как этого избежать.

2) Если все таки понадобиться календарь с заполненными ячейками , как заполнить ячейки числами с предыдущего месяца в начале календаря?

```js
 calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'));

 function calendar(div){
 
  var nowDate = new Date();
  var today = nowDate.getDate();
  var currentMonth = nowDate.getMonth();//ТЕКУЩИЙ МЕСЯЦ
  var currentYear = nowDate.getFullYear();
  var temp = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0);//колличество дней в текущем месяце
  var lastDay = temp.getDate();// последний день месяца
 
  var d = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1);//начало текущего месяца
  var currentDay = d.getDate();
  var table = document.createElement('table');
 
  var TEST = '<tr><td>Пн</td><td>Вт</td><td>Ср</td><td>Чт</td><td>Пт</td><td>Сб</td><td>Вс</td></tr>';
   table.innerHTML = TEST;
  
   var weekday = d.getDay() - 1;
   if(weekday < 0) { 
    weekday = 6; 
   }
  
   var a = 0;
   while(d.getMonth() == currentMonth){
   
    var i = 0;
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   
    while(i < 7){//пока i меньше чем кол-во дней недели
     var td = document.createElement('td');
     if(a == 0){
      if(i < weekday){
       //забиваем пустые значения
       td.innerText = '';
      }else{
       //заполняем числами первый ряд
       td.innerText = d.getDate();
       d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      }
     }else{
       //заполняем все остальные ряды
       td.innerText = d.getDate();
       d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      
       if(d.getDate() !== lastDay){
        console.log(d.getDate()); 
       }
      
     }//END ELSE
      tr.appendChild(td);
      i++;
      
    }//end while
    table.appendChild(tr);
   
    a++;
   }//end while
  
   div.appendChild(table);
 }//end calendar function
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного модифицировал функцию. Вторым аргументом теперь принимает значение 'true' или 'false', отвечающее за показывать ли предыдущий месяц (значение 'true') или текущий ('false').

```js
calendar(document.getElementById("calendar"), false);

function calendar(div, prevMonth){

    var nowDate = new Date();
    var today = nowDate.getDate();
    var currentMonth = nowDate.getMonth();//ТЕКУЩИЙ МЕСЯЦ
    var currentYear = nowDate.getFullYear();
    if ( prevMonth===true )
      if ( currentMonth==0 ){
        currentMonth = 11;
        currentYear--;
      } else {
       currentMonth--;
      }
    var temp = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0);//колличество дней в текущем месяце
    var lastDay = temp.getDate();// последний день месяца

    var d = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1);//начало текущего месяца
    var currentDay = d.getDate();
    var table = document.createElement('table');

    var TEST = '<tr><td>Пн</td><td>Вт</td><td>Ср</td><td>Чт</td><td>Пт</td><td>Сб</td><td>Вс</td></tr>';
    table.innerHTML = TEST;

    var weekday = d.getDay() - 1;
    if(weekday < 0) { 
      weekday = 6; 
    }
        
   var a = 0;
    while((d.getMonth() == currentMonth) && (d.getMonth()==currentMonth)){

      var i = 0;
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      
      while((i < 7)){//пока i меньше чем кол-во дней недели
    if ( d.getMonth()!=currentMonth ){
          break;
        }
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        if(a == 0){
          if (i < weekday){
            //забиваем пустые значения
            td.innerText = '';
          } else {
            //заполняем числами первый ряд
            td.innerText = d.getDate();
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
          }
        } else {
          //заполняем все остальные ряды
          td.innerText = d.getDate();
          d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

          if(d.getDate() !== lastDay){
            console.log(d.getDate());   
          }

        }//END ELSE
        tr.appendChild(td);
        i++;

      }//end while
      table.appendChild(tr);

      a++;
    }//end while

    div.appendChild(table);
}//end calendar function
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо. очень круто, выручил. я долго голову ломал=) все отлично работает